# Design of Datatypes: implicit or explicit State

Tags: haskell, types, abstract-data-type

I often encounter a problem in designing datatypes while handling some internal state. Assuming I have the following definition:

```
data Action a b c = Action { on :: a -> (c, b); off :: b -> a -> c }
```

Read: an action, which can be turned on or off (needing a value of type a, yielding some value of type c). For turning it off a special data of type b is needed which is given by a previous `on` call.

Now I design an action which keeps track of whether it is turned on or off:

```
data StatefulAction a b c = Off (Action a b c) | On b (Action a b c)
```

However I could also use this:

```
data State b = Off | On b   -- or type State b = Maybe b
data StatefulAction a b c = SA (Action a b c) (State b)
```

Which one is preferable?

Comment: Why not use State Monad, wrapping up b inside a state?

Comment: Also why not `data Action a b c = Off {on :: a -> (c,b)} | On {off :: b -> a -> c; bVal :: b}`

Comment: @Satvik because b is not a state, it is a piece of data unique for each action. The State Monad would just add unneeded complexity.
@is7s I need some function like `switch :: Action a b c -> a -> (c, Action a b c)`. This is not possible this way, consider `switch (Off on) a = let (c, b) = on a in On ??? b`

Answer (score 3):

Semantically, it is the exact same thing.

Syntactically, I guess you should choose what makes the code more readable. You can use `type` synonyms for this, as well.